# boost multiprecision gmp_float convert_to<double>() gives compilation error

Tags: boost, gmp, multiprecision, boost-multiprecision

I am using boost multiprecision library floating point number. I need to map a `gmp_float` to an `tanh` and then take it as a double because value of `tanh` will be `[0, 1)`. When I use `convert_to<double>()` I get compilation error as shown in the snippet bellow.

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::gmp_float<4>> float_type;

float_type previous_v = agent->_velocity(i, j);
float_type sigmapped_v = boost::multiprecision::tanh(previous_v);
double sigmoid_velocity = sigmapped_v.convert_to<double>();
// expected primary-expression before ‘double’ ^^

double v_probable = abs(sigmoid_velocity);
```

However explicitly casting it to double `(double)sigmapped_v` works

Comment: (If my hunch is correct, you left out important information from the question. If so, please consider including a /tested/ SSCCE next time)

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb, you are probably in a template context and `float_type` is a depends on a template argument.

You need to give the compiler type hints here:

```
double sigmoid_velocity = sigmapped_v.template convert_to<double>();
//                                    ^^
```

Without the disambiguation hint the compiler will parse `<` as `operator<`

See also [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)